# Using mozilla plataform to develop desktop applications

Tags: serial-port, mozilla

From what It seems mozilla platform was designed to be used focused in web development (browsers, e-mail clients, instant message...).

I want to use Mozilla platform to develop desktop applications that need most access to computer serial port and some applications that have nothing to do with web. I'm considering mozilla because it's multi-platform and easy to extend using themes and extensions.

Is it possible to program a serial terminal for example using mozilla? Does mozilla have any class ou framework that do this job or I`ll have to code for windows API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is definitely the way to go, there are two primary libraries for Java Serial Port programming, RxTx and JavaComm. This is a pretty good read on the subject: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java#Using_Java_for_Serial_Communication

**EDIT** I wouldn't rule out Mozilla as a front end but you won't be able to do serial port programming directly in XUL and javascript. That doesn't mean you are restricted just to XUL, I'd look at what Komodo Edit has done with the Mozilla platform and see just what you can expose to Java. I don't know if they use Java, I'd assume not but you may be able to see how to use and abuse the Mozilla platform. You might be able to write your Serial Code with Java or 'some other language' and an extensible interface with Mozilla's platform.

Mozilla's plugin system is fantastic.

Comment: I really need a plataform that can be easily extended with themes and extensions. That is why I was considering Mozilla as an option. Can I have this kind of requirement in java?

Answer (score 0):

I think Java which is also cross browser may be a better choice. Using Mozilla for this is a little like putting a screw in the wall with a hammer, it may work but it definitely is not the right tool for the job.